# Firebase Firestore Kotlin API error getting data into custom object: None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I try to use Firebase Firestore in a Kotlin Android project. I have an issue when I try to instantiate an object with DocumentSnapshot.toObject(Class valueType). I am trying to read a single object from a collection called 'news' with id eq 1. I can read the data but the API won't let me put the document into my custom object.

**News.kt**

```
data class News(
     val id : String? = "",
     val value : String? = ""
)
```

**HomeFragment.kt**

```
val db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()

var newsItem = db.collection("news").document("1")
newsItem.get()
    .addOnSuccessListener { documentSnapshot ->

        android.util.Log.d("TAG", "${documentSnapshot.id} => ${documentSnapshot.data}")

        var newsTextView : TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.homeNewsText)
        val newsText = documentSnapshot.toObject<News>()
    }
```

Error in IDE is:

> None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied.
> toObject(Class<News!>)   where T = News for    fun <T : Any!> toObject(valueType: Class<T!>): T? defined in com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot
> toObject(Class<News!>, DocumentSnapshot.ServerTimestampBehavior)   where T = News for    fun <T : Any!> toObject(valueType: Class<T!>, serverTimestampBehavior: DocumentSnapshot.ServerTimestampBehavior): T? defined in com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot

Thanks!

Comment: Fixed it by changing the toObject() call to:

```
val newsText = documentSnapshot.toObject<News>(News::class.java)
```

Not sure if it is intended to be used like that/ why this is necessary though

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you're not including the Kotlin Extensions (KTX) version of the Firebase SDK, which defines the generic overload of `toObject` that you're trying to use.

I'll show both options below, since this seems to be quite common.

---

#### Using the regular Java/Android SDK

Include the SDK with:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:21.5.0'
```

Get the object from the data with:

```
documentSnapshot.toObject(News::class.java)
```

---

#### Using the Android SDK with Kotlin Extensions

Include the SDK with:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore-ktx:21.5.0'
```

Get the object from the data with:

```
documentSnapshot.toObject<News>()
```

Comment: That solved it. Thank's a lot!
Might be a common error because the SDK was auto imported from the Firestore plugin within Android Studio.

Comment: Thanks for that info. That's good to know, because we were wondering where this came from. Let's hope that with your questions others can find the solution more easily.

Comment: I just fell into the exact same trap; Android Studio setup my deps for me & I followed the docs to the letter. Difficult to improve the docs; I guess you code prefix every KTX code sample with `// requires: implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore-ktx:21.5.0'`, but it's better to fix this on the Android Studio side; Kotlin project => import the KTX version.

Comment: Good point.  I'll ask around what we can do to improve this.